# stringbuffer and "0&" causes truncation or escaping

Tags: java, escaping, stringbuffer

Sorry for the unclear title but I don't even know what to call it, I'll just go ahead and explain what's happening.

I'm using a Stringbuffer to build an URL. It looks like this:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=49.0516736,8.38891840&sensor=false
```

I encountered this behavious when comparing this string in a Unit-test to the actual result of the method.

And this is the assertion-error I'm getting:

```
latlng=49.0516736[,8.38891840]&sensor=false> but was:<...on?latlng=49.0516736[,8.3889184]&sensor=false
```

The emphasis is on the character sequence **0]&** and **4]&** right before **sensor=false**

IF I remove the zero before the **&** the test goes green.

then the created string looks like this:

```
latlng=49.0516736,8.3889184&sensor=false
```

so ... just as expected.
It's not the problem, that the 0 itself gets truncated and test would fail - I've proved that my code is doing what it's supposed to (when I remove the zero), but I want to know what is happening here.

**0&** must be some kind of indication for array-access or some kind of escaping. I don't know. 
Anyone any idea what's causing this behaviour?

Edit:

Here's the code I'm using

```
StringBuffer s = new StringBuffer( grailsApplication.config.geocodingurl.toString() )
s.append(coordinates.latitude)
s.append(",")
s.append(coordinates.longitude)
s.append("&sensor=false")
return s.toString()
```

Comment: Are you using `StringBuilder.append(float)` to add the "8.388..." portion?

Comment: Yes, show us the code used to generate this URL. We don't see your screen.

Comment: do i understand you correctly? are you asking why junit says that string `...1840&senso...` is different from string `...184&seno...` ?

Comment: yes I am using `append(double)` (not float) and no I'm not wondering why they differ and the assert-statement fails - that's clear ;)

Answer (score 4):

There is a formatting/padding issue when converting `double` into `String`.

What you are doing is probably using [StringBuilder#append(double)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28double%29) which in the end calls [Double#toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#toString%28double%29).

See the javadoc of those methods and find out how `double` values are converted to `String`.
Alternatively, if you want to have control over your code, use [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) or it's subclasses.

Comment: thanks, I'll read through it - coming back for further questions